# MYSQL User creation syntax error on previously working code after sed replace for password

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to enable Replication between master and slave to do one-way replication. I have to create the MySQL statements and sed replace the password in the command so its masked with Jenkins credentials.

MY MySQL instance is Amazon RDS. The thing is before I implemented the sed while I was testing locally I had the password just hardcoded in the command and it worked no issue so I think I just messed up some syntax somewhere that I'm not seeing.

MySQL Version: MySQL 5.7.19

This worked when I had the password hard coded. I'm not sure what I'm

This is the output from the Jenkins job running the command.
Output:

```
16:55:48 ==================== Create Replication User and Grant Permissions on Old Database =========================
#This is the command that is being ran to try and fix the create user issue.
16:55:48 DROP USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
16:55:48 mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
16:55:48 ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1
16:55:48 mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
16:55:48 ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1
16:55:48 mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
16:55:48 mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

#The second command to be ran
16:55:48 CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
16:55:48 mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
16:55:48 ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'user'@'%'
16:55:48 mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
16:55:49 ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'user'@'%'

#Third command to be ran
16:55:49 GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON main.tf variables.tf x_dev.backend.tf x_usdev.amis.tf x_useast.region.tf TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
16:55:49 mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

16:55:49 ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'variables.tf x_dev.backend.tf x_usdev.amis.tf x_useast.region.tf TO 'user'@' at line 1
16:55:49 mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
16:55:49 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'variables.tf x_dev.backend.tf x_usdev.amis.tf x_useast.region.tf TO 'user'@' at line 1
```

The Code being ran.

```
function create_users_and_grant_replication_old {

 drop_user_statement="DROP USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MYSQL_PASSWORD';"
 drop_user_statement=$(echo $drop_user_statement | sed -e "s/MYSQL_PASSWORD/${MYSQL_PASSWORD}/g")

 echo "${drop_user_statement}"

 mysql -h ${global_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${drop_user_statement}"
 mysql -h ${tenant_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${drop_user_statement}"

 mysql -h ${global_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "flush privileges;"
 mysql -h ${tenant_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "flush privileges;"

  mysql_statement=""
  mysql_statement="CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MYSQL_PASSWORD';"
  mysql_statement=$(echo $mysql_statement | sed -e "s/MYSQL_PASSWORD/${MYSQL_PASSWORD}/g")
  echo "${mysql_statement}"

  mysql -h ${global_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${mysql_statement}"
  mysql -h ${tenant_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${mysql_statement}"

  mysql_statement=""
  mysql_statement="GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MYSQL_PASSWORD';"
  mysql_statement=$(echo $mysql_statement | sed -e "s/MYSQL_PASSWORD/${MYSQL_PASSWORD}/g")
  echo "${mysql_statement}"

  mysql -h ${global_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${mysql_statement}"
  mysql -h ${tenant_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${mysql_statement}"

}
```

I have fixed the drop user and flush privillages section where user creation is working but the grant replication is still saying its having a syntax error.

```
17:27:12 GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON main.tf variables.tf x_dev.backend.tf x_usdev.amis.tf x_useast.region.tf TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

This is the problem, teh *.* picks up the files of the directory no matter how I sed replace it.

main.tf variables.tf x_dev.backend.tf x_usdev.amis.tf

```
    mysql_statement=""
 mysql_statement=$(echo 'GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO "repl_user"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "MYSQL_PASSWORD";' | sed -e "s/MYSQL_PASSWORD/${MYSQL_PASSWORD}/g")
 echo "${mysql_statement}"

 #echo "${mysql_statement}"
 #mysql_statement=$(echo $mysql_statement | sed -e "s/\"/\'/g")
 #echo "${mysql_statement}"

 mysql -h ${global_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${mysql_statement}"
 mysql -h ${tenant_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${mysql_statement}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the quotes around the echo for the sed, and needed to clear the user and flush privileges.. Here is the correct working answer code.

```
function create_users_and_grant_replication_old {
 drop_user_statement="DROP USER 'repl_user';"
 drop_user_statement=$(echo "$drop_user_statement" | sed -e "s/MYSQL_PASSWORD/${MYSQL_PASSWORD}/g")

 mysql -h ${global_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${drop_user_statement}"
 mysql -h ${tenant_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${drop_user_statement}"

 mysql -h ${global_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "flush privileges;"
 mysql -h ${tenant_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "flush privileges;"

 mysql_statement=""
 mysql_statement="CREATE USER 'repl_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MYSQL_PASSWORD';"
 mysql_statement=$(echo "$mysql_statement" | sed -e "s/MYSQL_PASSWORD/${MYSQL_PASSWORD}/g")

 mysql -h ${global_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${mysql_statement}"
 mysql -h ${tenant_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${mysql_statement}"

 mysql_statement=""
 mysql_statement='GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO "repl_user"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "MYSQL_PASSWORD";'
 mysql_statement=$(echo "$mysql_statement" | sed -e "s/MYSQL_PASSWORD/${MYSQL_PASSWORD}/g")
 mysql_statement=$(echo "$mysql_statement" | sed -e "s/\"/\'/g")

 mysql -h ${global_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${mysql_statement}"
 mysql -h ${tenant_database_endpoint_old} -u ${MYSQL_USERNAME} --port=3306 --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" -Bse "${mysql_statement}"
}
```